# Autowired annotation returns null in AuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my Spring Security application, I am trying to return cookie 'remember_token' after successful login. My **AuthenticanSuccessHandler**  class auto wires **RememberMeService** class to get 'token' value from database. But autowired reference **rememberMeService** returns null. I did mention **@Component** annotation for the class, but it did not change the result.  [Link to complete source code](https://github.com/jpavanaryan/FastCheck)

**FormAuthenticationSuccessHandler**:

```
package com.fastcheck.timesheet.common.security;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.fastcheck.timesheet.common.services.RememberMeService;


@Component
public class FormAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
    @Autowired
    public RememberMeService rememberMeService;

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException
{

    String username;
    Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) 
        {
            username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        } 
        else 
        {
            username = principal.toString();

        }

    System.out.println("rememberMeService :"+rememberMeService);
    if(rememberMeService != null)
        {
            Cookie cookie=new Cookie("remember_token",rememberMeService.getRememberMeToken(username));
            cookie.setMaxAge(200);
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }


    response.setStatus(200);
    response.sendRedirect("home");


}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I understand from your code is that you are trying to achieve what spring security is created to do out-of-the-box for you.

If you implemented spring security properly, I don't see why remember-me token will not be stored automatically on the user's browser after a successful authentication as you are trying to do.

Comment: It is storing some junk value. Not actual Token value

Comment: Wait a minute. Hope you are not expecting that the information spring security saves on the browser will be the same as that stored in the persistent table? If that has been your expectation, then you have misunderstood spring security remember-me concept. The vital information you call junk is a hash combination of username, a randomly generated series identifier and a randomly generated token value. Spring security will decode this and compare with that stored in the persistent table during remember-me authentication.

Comment: Please read this link for a better understanding of the whole concept. http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice

Comment: You are right Perry. I need to decode remember_token. Can you post this as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: You already have accepted another answer. You possibly did not check name before accepting the answer. Well, its ok if you found it helpful as well. All the best. Keep coding.

Comment: Let me change that.

Comment: I am grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remember token automatically sent to the browser. You don't need to send it separately. Would it be possible to provide cookie value returned by browser? otherwise please use below script to decode it.

```
String cookieAsPlainText = new String(Base64.decode(cookies[i].getValue());
```

**cookieAsPlainText** as plain value should be **series:token** format. Please let me know if this helps